# Getting System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException while Consuming WCF Webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I am consuming a WCF web service to which i have no control in web service side.

I have given a auto generated svc.cs proxy file by which i am consuming it.

Actually i am requesting to the web service to download some large data from client side.

Sometimes i am getting

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException

in my Client side.

Exception is as follow:

> **System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The number of bytes available
>   is inconsistent with the HTTP Content-Length header.  There may have
>   been a network error or the client may be sending invalid requests.**
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream
>   inputStream)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception&
>   requestException)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at IBulkDataSvc.GetEmployeesData(String
>   BusinessPath, DateTime EffectiveDate, String TerminalName)    at
>   Empower.ServiceRequest.EmployeeDataXML(DateTime time, String terminal)
>   at Empower.Empower.DownloadEmployeeList(String terminalName)

My web service binding config in client side is as follow(only showing bindings),

```
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BulkDataSvcSoap">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BulkDataSvcHttpsSoap">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="BulkDataSvcTcp">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

**I am little bit of confused from which end it is really generated and why it is generating?**

I have googled and did not fine anything much helpful.So can some one please help me out from this puzzle
.

Comment: Did you enable logging in the WCF services to analyze. This alone can give better insights into the issue you are running into now. Analysis of the log file can help you. Or post the exception detail from the svclog file for us.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a chance to read this [calling non wcf service](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5c3fdeb-65da-4d72-90eb-4c5c31e582d1/nonwcf-service-responds-with-wrong-contentlength-header-protocolexception?forum=wcf)

Also, in some cases iF your request is bringing data larger than what is specified at webservice side then you are bound to get this.